# Pidgin icon not showing up in system tray

Tags: pidgin, system-tray

I uninstalled `indicator-messages` because I'd rather have separate icons for my programs. The problem I have now is that `pidgin` icon won't show up (while others do, like `empathy`, `skype` and so on). Or to be more precise, it shows up but is transparent:

[image: Invisible pidgin icon spotted!]

When I use the main launcher and there is the dark effect on the top bar, here is how it looks (black square):

[image]

To summarize where I'm at with the packages, I've uninstalled:

- `indicator-messages`
- `indicator-status-provider-mc5`
- `indicator-status-provider-pidgin`

And systray whitelist is set to `['all']` already.

Comment: @RolandTaylor not a duplicate, systray whitelist is set to all already.

Comment: oh okay, I think I know what your problem is now.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the pidgin status provider:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-status-provider-pidgin
```

Then restart Pidgin and it's icon should show up. If it does not, then just make sure to double check that you have Pidgin's tray icon enabled in its preferences (in case this option was disabled when you had the indicator installed).

To be completely certain (now I noticed that the icon is there but transparent), check the following:

- Ensure that you are using the default icon theme in pidgin.
- Try using one of the default Ubuntu icon themes if you are not already.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled the indicator status provider and checked all the other points but the problem is still there. Strange! Thanks for helping out though :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can get back to the original transparent icon I suggest that you try changing your theme, as follows:

1. Select the gear in the top right of your screen
2. Choose "Appearance"
3. On the default "Look" tab, toward the bottom, is a
   place to select an alternate theme.

I've seen a case where a program was using an icon without sufficient contrast with the chosen theme and the problem was eliminated by using a different theme, and therefore a different top panel background color.

Comment: doesn't solve the program - exact same symptoms (trasparent icon when in normal mode and black square when launcher is on). Thanks for helping though it's appreciated :)

Comment: s/program/problem/